# PIN required - Cannot deploy Python code out of Visual Studio 2015 onto Raspberry Pi 2 B

Tags: python, visual-studio, deployment, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to deploy my first Python project onto a Raspberry Pi 2 B via Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. The Pi runs Windows 10 Core IoT and I can connect to it via SSH and the web interface with no problem.

My issue is that I get Error DEP6200 during deployment. **VS asks for a PIN during deployment that I cannot provide**. It's not the OS's login password nor any standard PIN you might expect (eg 0000 or 1234).

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

try changing Authentication to None in App Properties while deploying/ debugging.

Can be found Debug -> Properties -> Authentication (Select 'None')

Answer (score 0):

I was still getting errors after switching the authentication to "None". I had to add the port number after the remote machine name. 
MyPi3:8116

I also noticed that msvcmon.exe was running as administrator on the pi. I switched it to run as the DefaultAccount. I'm not sure if this was necessary. I'll switch it back to administrator later. You can shut it down from the processes link then on the debugging link, start it back up and check the box for DefaultAccount.